# Line replacement in directories clears the whole files?

Tags: ruby, replace

I am trying to recursively replace a whole line from `index.html` files into a directory with sub-directories.

The code above puts the right lines I'm searching with the var "pattern", but when I run it, it removes everything form my index.html files.

```
pattern = "Keyword"

replacement = "<td width=\"30\"><img src=\"styles/img/trans.gif\" width=\"30\"></td>"

Dir.glob('/Users/root/Desktop/directory/test/**/index.html') do |item|
    next unless File.file?(item)
        File.open(item, "w+:ASCII-8BIT") do |f|
            f.each_line do |line|
                if line.match(pattern)
                    my_line = line
                    line.sub(my_line, replacement)
                end     
        end 
    end 
end
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: are you sure your `index.html` is more than one line? Do a simple count instead of `sub` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *read* the file first, *build* the expected output, and then *write* it:

```
Dir.glob('/Users/root/Desktop/directory/test/**/index.html') do |item|
  next unless File.file?(item)
    output = IO.readlines(item).map do |line|
      if line.match(pattern)
        replacement
      else
        line
      end
    end 
    File.open(item, "w+:ASCII-8BIT") do |f|
      f.write output.join
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: Indeed, I was missing the separation between reading and writing. Your code works when I "puts output.join". It prints the whole file with the line remplacement, but it makes an empty file.

Comment: Oops, my fault, I was missing the f.write method. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You use `File.open` with open mode `w+` which, according to Ruby documentation, is:

> "w+" Read-write, truncates existing file to zero length or creates a new file for reading and writing.

To read the file and put some lines use `r`:

```
File.open(item, "r:ASCII-8BIT")
```

Comment: Instead of using `w+` use `a` for append.